# Consume ASP .NET WebService In php

Tags: php, asp.net, web-services

Hey guys
I am trying to consume ASP webservice in my php script.
But i am stuck in one problem.

```
 require_once('lib/nusoap.php');
    $soapClient = new   SoapClient("http://test.etech.net/PanelIntegration/PanelIntegration.asmx?wsdl");  

 $sh_param = array( 
                    'Username'    =>    'mueksh', 
                    'Password'    =>    'bisht');
```

and i am using **UpdateInstruction method**

```
$result->call("UpdateInstruction ",$sh_param);
```

Now in return i have get Username and Passsword not Supplied.
Can anybody tell me where i am wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the PHP5 standard SoapClient class instead of NuSoap (which was developed for PHP4 because it had no native SOAP support) and use [SoapClient::__getLastRequest()](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php) to find out exactly what XML the Soap call is generating.